# Show that given sequence is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that given sequence$\{S_n\} $ is convergent.

$$S_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+.....+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}$$

is convergent.

**My input:**

$S_n = 1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{3!}+.....+\dfrac{1}{(n-1)!}<1+\dfrac{1}{1!}+\dfrac{1}{2!}+\dfrac{1}{2^2}...=1+1+1=3$

$S_n<3$

Given sequence is increasing and we have proved that it's bounded above by $3$. Thus making it a convergent sequence. Is it a correct approach to solve this problem? Any other way I could've solved this?

Comment: Seems correct and nice.

Comment: @Cornman I didn't realise that we were taking the limit of $S_{n}$, my bad.

Comment: Just to note some technicalities. On your inequality you have used $S_n$  to mean at least two different things - you need to call the right-hand side $T$ or something else. You shouldn't use $T_n$ (or $S_n$) for the infinite sum. You might want $S_n\lt T_n\lt T$ so that $\lim S_n \le T$. You have indicated a geometric series comparison, but you should give the general term to make this explicit. There are more delicate tests of convergence available, but you have taken advantage of the rapid convergence here to make an easy and quick comparison.

Comment: @MarkBennet That was useful thanks.

Comment: Yes this is right, but the explanation is a little short. One may wonder where $1+1+1$ comes from (not counting the typo). Would be good to say for $n>2$, $1/n!<2^{-n}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Edited that typo though and formally I could use your telling in my exam thanks :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ratio test, so:
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \div \frac{1}{n!}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}<1\forall n>0$$

Comment: Ratio test for sequences is different from ratio test for series right? For sequences it is $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l; $ convergent if $l<|1|$ right ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

The standard way of proving that this sequence converges is to use the **ratio test:** if $(a_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$, then the sequence $a_0+a_1+a_2+\cdots$ converges.

Comment: The ratio test is essentially a comparison to a geometric series.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct, as an alternative we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{(k-1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{(k-1)!}$$

which converges for example by comparison test with $\sum \frac 1{k^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$u_n=1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i!}$$
and

$$v_n=u_n+\frac{1}{nn!}$$

It is easy to prove that $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are adjacent and therefore convergent.

You can also use this to prove that the limit $e\notin \Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0):

An option:

Let $k\ge 2$.

$\dfrac{1}{k!} \le \dfrac{1}{k(k-1)} = \dfrac{1}{k-1} - \dfrac{1}{k}.$

We have

$\displaystyle {\sum_{k=2}^{n}} \dfrac{1}{k!} \le \displaystyle{ \sum_{k=2}^{n}}[ \dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}] =$

$1- \dfrac{1}{n}.$

1) $S_n=\displaystyle{ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}}\dfrac{1}{k!}$ is strictly increasing,

2) $S_n$ is bounded above by $3$ (why?),

hence convergent.